# How to define descendant order index on symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I want to create following an index to PostgreSQL in Doctrine.

```
CREATE INDEX xxxx ON my_table (start_date, end_date DESC);
```

I wrote annotation in entity comments, but SchemaException error occurred.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(
 *     Indexes={
 *         @ORM\Index(columns={"start_date", "end_date DESC"})
 *     }
 * }
 */
 class MyTable
 {
     // snip
 }
```

How i should write "DESC" keyword annotation?

Comment: Full error message when to run doctrine:schema:update command. "[Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\SchemaException] There is no column with name 'end_date DESC' on table 'my_table'."

Comment: I don't think Doctrine supports that take a look at [this](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-index), there is nothing about index order in the platform specific `options`.